# Changing locally a specific math font size

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, math-fonts

This is my first message on TeX exchange, please forgive me if the format of my question is not appropriate (I don't even know how to produce a LaTeX compilation of the message)

I am using the following preamble with LaTeX (MikTeX distribution):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{amscd,amssymb,amsthm,latexsym,stmaryrd,xypic,amsmath}
\xyoption{all}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
```

At some point, I am using the letters `$\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{P}$ and $\mathcal{P}$` in two contexts:

1) these letters appear by themselves : let `$\mathfrak{P}$` be an ideal...

2) they appear in indices: let `$[x]_\mathfrak{P}$` be the class of `$x$` modulo `$\mathfrak{P}$`.

My problem is that I would like to reduce the size of these letters only  when used for indexing (as in 2)).
I tried `\footnotesize`, `\small`, `\fontsize{12}{8}`...but nothing works. The size stays the same over and over...

I start suspecting that I have to create a new font `\mathfrak` and `\mathcal`, for example by modifying the existing defining files for these fonts and force a smaller size , but it is way out of my league.

Could someone tell me how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: As always on the site please pot full but minimal examples, not sniplets like this. We cannot test them without guessing and that is a waste of time. Pluse NEVER rely on `_\mathfrak{P}` working always use `_{\mathfrak{P}}` it is pure luck that it currently works and might not in the future.

Comment: Additionally whay are you using both `xypic ` and `tikz-cd` at the same time? Use the latter, it is vastly more powerfull.

Comment: I tried also with _{\mathfrak{P}}, it does not work either...

Comment: As I said: full minimal example, otherwise people will just ignore your question as there are many other questions to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that `x_{\mathfrak{P}}` the P is not smaller than `\mathfrak{P}` ? That would be very odd.   However   `x_{\scriptscriptstyle\mathfrak{P}}` will make it smaller still.

Note that x should not be braced, but `\mathfrac{P}` should be braced in `x_{\mathfrak{P}}`

Comment: I tried the \scriptscriptstyle solution, and it works perfectly, thanks :-)